# Importing a .max or .nwd files into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d-model

A client provided me with a .max and .nwd formate 3D model for a site. I'm trying to get it into ArcGIS Pro but these formats appears to be unsupported. Has anyone had any success converting .max formated 3D files into Pro? How about with .nwd?

I don't have 3D Max, so I can't open and convert.

Comment: This is an AutoDesk 3-D file type and not supported in ArcPro.  Ask the data  provider to  export these data to AutoDesk .dxf or .dwg.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Pro will not support .nwd file, so convert this file into IFC or Revit.

IFC file import using interoperability extension in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, all data stored in personal geodatabase as Multipatch files.

Revit file you can open directly in ArcGIS Pro. Recent ArcGIS Pro 2.5 version can convert directly revit file into Multipatch files.